# Unintended Proxy Settings Found on my Windows 10 PC - Possible Malware Infection?

Tags: windows, networking, server, proxy, malware

I recently discovered that my Windows computer has proxy settings configured as follows:

Proxy Server: [Address:Port]
`http=127.0.0.1:6545;https=127.0.0.1:6545;socks=127.0.0.1:6544`

Configured to use proxy server except for the following entries.

```
10.*;172.16.*;172.17.*;172.18.*;172.19.*;172.20.*;172.21.*;172.22.*;172.23.*;172.24.*;172.25.*;172.26.*;172.27.*;172.28.*;172.29.*;172.30.*;172.31.*;192.168.*;169.254.*;[fc*];[fd*];[fe8*];[fe9*];[fea*];[feb*]
```

This prevented me from accessing the internet from any browser.
I did not intentionally set these proxy configurations; I suspect my computer might be infected with malware.
Could these proxy settings be a result of malware? If so, what could be the potential damage caused by such malware, and how can I mitigate its impact?

[image: Disabled Use Proxy]